# Marcar ou desmaracar selectBooleanCheckbox ao clicar em outro

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Olá, estou com a seguinte situação:
Na minha página jsf tenho alguns componentes `selectBooleanCheckbox`. Preciso que, ao clicar em um deles alguns outros sejam desmarcados, e também desabilitados, impossibilitando sua seleção.
È possível? Se sim, alguém tem alguma informação, material que possa me ajudar? Obrigado

xhtml:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaCliente}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cliente" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondutor}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Condutor" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondicaoTempo}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cond. Tempo" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaOcorrencia}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Ocorrência" />
```

No bean:

```
boolean colunaId = false, colunaCliente = false, colunaCondutor = false, colunaPeriodo = false,
        colunaCondicaoTempo = false, colunaStatus = false, colunaOcorrencia = false, colunaSoma = false,
        colunaQtdCond = false, colunaQtdCli = false;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Update 01:**

xhtml

```
<p:toolbar id="colunas" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="#{simpleReport.colunaId}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cód." />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cli"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaCliente}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cliente" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cond"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondutor}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Condutor" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="CondTemp"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaCondicaoTempo}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cond. Tempo" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ocor"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaOcorrencia}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Ocorrência" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sta"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaStatus}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Status" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="per"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaPeriodo}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Período" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="soma"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaSoma}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Soma" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="qtdCli"
                        value="#{simpleReport.colunaQtdCli}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="QtdCli" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{simpleReport.colunaQtdCondTemp}" />
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="Qtd Cond Temp." />


                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="groupCLiente"
                        value="#{simpleReport.groupByCLiente}">
                        <p:ajax update="id cond CondTemp ocor sta per"
                            listener="#{simpleReport.resetValue1}" />
                        <h:outputText escape="false" value="Cliente" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="groupCondicao"
                        value="#{simpleReport.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
                        <p:ajax update="id cond CondTemp ocor sta per"
                            listener="#{simpleReport.resetCondicaoTempo}" />
                        <h:outputText escape="false" value="Condição" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:toolbarGroup>

            </p:toolbar>
```

No bean:

```
public void resetValue1() {
    this.colunaId = false;
    this.colunaCondutor = false;
    this.colunaCondicaoTempo = false;
    this.colunaOcorrencia = false;
    this.colunaStatus = false;
    this.colunaPeriodo = false;
    this.colunaSoma = false;
}

public void resetCondicaoTempo() {
    this.colunaId = false;
    this.colunaCondutor = false;
    this.colunaOcorrencia = false;
    this.colunaStatus = false;
    this.colunaPeriodo = false;
    this.colunaSoma = false;
}

public void resetCondutor() {
    this.colunaId = false;
    this.colunaCondicaoTempo = false;
    this.colunaOcorrencia = false;
    this.colunaStatus = false;
    this.colunaPeriodo = false;
    this.colunaSoma = false;
}
```

**Update02:**

xhtml:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="#{simpleReport.colunaId}"
                        disabled="#{simpleReport.groupByCLiente || simpleReport.groupByCondicaoTempo}"
                        enabled="#{not simpleReport.groupByCLiente}"/>
```

Comment: Encontrei este post no SOen : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709112/single-select-checkbox-using-jsf , basicamente é o que preciso mas não consegui implementar ainda pois, no meu caso, ao clicar em um dos `selectBooleanCheckbox`preciso  desmarcar mais de um.

Comment: Não sei se isso se adapta a sua necessidade, mas você não poderia utilizar ao invés de Checkbox um Radiogroup

Comment: @ R.Santos creio que devido as várias opções que preciso controlar não seria uma boa opção.Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o componente [Radio](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) pode ser uma alternativa, mas se precisar de um controle mais personalizado, pode tentar fazer da seguinte forma:

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No XHTML:

```
<h:panelGroup id="pnlOpcoes">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.opcao1}" disabled="#{controlador.selecionouAlgumCheck()}">
    <p:ajax update="pnlOpcoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção 1 - Ativa se nenhuma estiver ativa" />
<br />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.subOpcao1}" disabled="#{not controlador.opcao1}" />
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção ativa somente se a 1 estiver ativa" />
<br />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.opcao2}" disabled="#{controlador.selecionouAlgumCheck()}">
    <p:ajax update="pnlOpcoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção 2 - Ativa se nenhuma estiver ativa" />
<br />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.subOpcao2}" disabled="#{not controlador.opcao2}">
    <p:ajax update="pnlOpcoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção ativa somente se a 2 estiver ativa" />
<br />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.opcao3}" disabled="#{controlador.selecionouAlgumCheck()}">
    <p:ajax update="pnlOpcoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção 3 - Ativa se nenhuma estiver ativa" />
<br />

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.opcao4}" disabled="#{controlador.selecionouAlgumCheck() and not controlador.opcao2}">
    <p:ajax update="pnlOpcoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Opção 4 - Ativa somente se nenhuma estiver ativa ou se a 2 estiver ativa" /><br />
</h:panelGroup>

<p />

<p:commandButton action="#{controlador.inicializarCheck()}" update="pnlOpcoes" value="Reset" />
```

No Bean:

```
private boolean opcao1;
private boolean subOpcao1;

private boolean opcao2;
private boolean subOpcao2;

private boolean opcao3;
private boolean opcao4;

public boolean isOpcao1() {

    return this.opcao1;
}

public void setOpcao1(boolean opcao1) {

    this.inicializarCheck();
    this.opcao1 = opcao1;
}

public boolean isSubOpcao1() {

    return this.subOpcao1;
}

public void setSubOpcao1(boolean subOpcao1) {

    this.subOpcao1 = subOpcao1;
}

public boolean isOpcao2() {

    return this.opcao2;
}

public void setOpcao2(boolean opcao2) {

    this.inicializarCheck();
    this.opcao2 = opcao2;
}

public boolean isSubOpcao2() {

    return this.subOpcao2;
}

public void setSubOpcao2(boolean subOpcao2) {

    this.subOpcao2 = subOpcao2;
}

public boolean isOpcao3() {

    return this.opcao3;
}

public void setOpcao3(boolean opcao3) {

    this.inicializarCheck();
    this.opcao3 = opcao3;
}

public boolean isOpcao4() {

    return this.opcao4;
}

public void setOpcao4(boolean opcao4) {

    boolean opcao2 = this.opcao2;
    boolean subOpcao2 = this.subOpcao2;
    this.inicializarCheck();
    this.opcao4 = opcao4;
    this.opcao2 = opcao2;
    this.subOpcao2 = subOpcao2;
}

public void inicializarCheck() {
    this.opcao1 = false;
    this.subOpcao1 = false;
    this.opcao2 = false;
    this.subOpcao2 = false;
    this.opcao3 = false;
    this.opcao4 = false;
}

public boolean selecionouAlgumCheck() {
    return this.opcao1 || this.opcao2 || this.opcao3 || this.opcao4;
}
```

Comment: Consegui algo neste meio tempo, desde que postei a dúvida, logo mais posto os códigos e também vejo com calma sua resposta, obrigado.

Comment: @ Marcus Martins adicionei os códigos que estou usando no momento ( update 01), agora vou ver a sua resposta. Mas já percebi que seu código a primeira vista já impossibilita o usuário de selecionar as opções desativadas, o que é bastante interessante, no meu só desmarca as opções desejadas.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu resolver. Se precisar de ajudar, pode perguntar.

Comment: Sem problemas, ainda não pude "adaptar" sua sugestão no meu código. Quando fizer dou retorno! Obrigado

Comment: @ Marcus Martins poderia me ajudar a fazer com que ao selecionar (por exemplo) a selectBooleanCheckbox `groupCLiente` as opções que forem desmarcadas devido a sua seleção também sejam desabilitadas impossibilitando sua seleção ? Até que ela (`groupCliente`)seja desselecionada? Obrigado.

Comment: Acrescentei uma outra parte de código, somente usei uma parte da sugestão do @Marcus Martins e adaptei ao meu código, está em : update02, agora está desabilitando o `selectBooleanCheckBox` especificado quando seleciono um outro, e ao desselecionar o que foi selecionado, ele está habilitando novamente ( o desabilitado). Ainda preciso fazer outros ajustes (outros `selectBooleanCheckBox` ) mas creio que estou no caminho. Como esses `selectBooleanCheckBox` irão alterar minha `query`é importante " desabilitar" e poder "habilitá-los" novamente nos cliques.

Comment: @Rodrigo, desculpe a demora, mas só consegui acessar hoje. Postei um outro exemplo com a opção de ativar/desativar em grupos, usando seu exemplo de groupByCliente / groupByCondicaoTempo.

Answer (score 2):

Outro solução, usando a implementação de ativar/desativar em grupos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No XHTML:

```
<p:toolbar id="colunas" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <p:toolbarGroup>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaId}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Cód." />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaCliente}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Cliente" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaCondutor}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Condutor" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaCondicaoTempo}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Cond. Tempo" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaOcorrencia}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Ocorrência" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaStatus}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Status" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaPeriodo}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Período" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaSoma}" disabled="#{controlador.groupByCLiente || controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Soma" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaQtdCli}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="QtdCli" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.colunaQtdCond}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <h:outputText value="Qtd Cond Temp." />
    </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>

<p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
    <p:toolbarGroup>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.groupByCLiente}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
            <h:outputText value="Cliente" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{controlador.groupByCondicaoTempo}">
            <p:ajax update="colunas" />
            <h:outputText value="Condição" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

No Bean:

```
private boolean colunaId = false,
                colunaCliente = false,
                colunaCondutor = false,
                colunaPeriodo = false,
                colunaCondicaoTempo = false,
                colunaStatus = false,
                colunaOcorrencia = false,
                colunaSoma = false,
                colunaQtdCond = false,
                colunaQtdCli = false,
                groupByCLiente = false,
                groupByCondicaoTempo = false;

public boolean getColunaId() {
    return this.colunaId;
}

public void setColunaId(boolean colunaId) {
    this.colunaId = colunaId;
}

public boolean getColunaCliente() {
    return this.colunaCliente;
}

public void setColunaCliente(boolean colunaCliente) {
    this.colunaCliente = colunaCliente;
}

public boolean getColunaCondutor() {
    return this.colunaCondutor;
}

public void setColunaCondutor(boolean colunaCondutor) {
    this.colunaCondutor = colunaCondutor;
}

public boolean getColunaPeriodo() {
    return this.colunaPeriodo;
}

public void setColunaPeriodo(boolean colunaPeriodo) {
    this.colunaPeriodo = colunaPeriodo;
}

public boolean getColunaCondicaoTempo() {
    return this.colunaCondicaoTempo;
}

public void setColunaCondicaoTempo(boolean colunaCondicaoTempo) {
    this.colunaCondicaoTempo = colunaCondicaoTempo;
}

public boolean getColunaStatus() {
    return this.colunaStatus;
}

public void setColunaStatus(boolean colunaStatus) {
    this.colunaStatus = colunaStatus;
}

public boolean getColunaOcorrencia() {
    return this.colunaOcorrencia;
}

public void setColunaOcorrencia(boolean colunaOcorrencia) {
    this.colunaOcorrencia = colunaOcorrencia;
}

public boolean getColunaSoma() {
    return this.colunaSoma;
}

public void setColunaSoma(boolean colunaSoma) {
    this.colunaSoma = colunaSoma;
}

public boolean getColunaQtdCond() {
    return this.colunaQtdCond;
}

public void setColunaQtdCond(boolean colunaQtdCond) {
    this.colunaQtdCond = colunaQtdCond;
}

public boolean getColunaQtdCli() {
    return this.colunaQtdCli;
}

public void setColunaQtdCli(boolean colunaQtdCli) {
    this.colunaQtdCli = colunaQtdCli;
}

public boolean getGroupByCLiente() {
    return this.groupByCLiente;
}

public void setGroupByCLiente(boolean groupByCLiente) {
    this.groupByCLiente = groupByCLiente;
    this.resetByCliente(false);
}

public boolean getGroupByCondicaoTempo() {
    return this.groupByCondicaoTempo;
}

public void setGroupByCondicaoTempo(boolean groupByCondicaoTempo) {
    this.groupByCondicaoTempo = groupByCondicaoTempo;
    this.resetByCondicaoTempo(false);
}

public void resetByCliente(boolean valor) {
    this.colunaId = valor;
    this.colunaCondutor = valor;
    this.colunaCondicaoTempo = valor;
    this.colunaOcorrencia = valor;
    this.colunaStatus = valor;
    this.colunaPeriodo = valor;
    this.colunaSoma = valor;
}

public void resetByCondicaoTempo(boolean valor) {
    this.colunaId = valor;
    this.colunaCondutor = valor;
    this.colunaOcorrencia = valor;
    this.colunaStatus = valor;
    this.colunaPeriodo = valor;
    this.colunaSoma = valor;
}
```