# Estou querendo que ao clicar em um radio button em jsf com primefaces desabilite um inputText

Tags: jsf, hibernate, primefaces, jpa

```
                <p:inputText id="txtCidadeFora" value="#{moradorRuaBean.moradorRua.cidade}"
                     disabled="#{moradorRuaBean.ishabilitaCidade == false}"></pmf:campoTexto>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

No managedBean criei a variavel booleana

Comment: Tente ver se essa solução atende ao que vc precisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161962/marcar-ou-desmaracar-selectbooleancheckbox-ao-clicar-em-outro/

Answer (score 0):

Como você já tem uma variável `boolean` no `bean` associado ao `selectOneRadio`, desta forma, quando o valor deste componente for alterado, será armazenado no `bean`, então, basta você colocar um `<p:ajax />` para atualizar o componente `<p:inputText/>`. Por exemplo:

```
<p:selectOneRadio>
<p:ajax event=“change” update=“txtCidadeFora” />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```